# How to convert RDD like ((int, int), int) into 3 key-value pairs in one map function in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Right now I have a RDD in the following format

```
( (int, int), int )
```

and I'm trying to convert it into 3 key-value pairs like (int, 1).

I can do this by using 3 map functions then join them together, but it's definitely not the best way to implement it,

also by using case I can generate a list of ((int, 1), (int, 1), (int, 1)), but how can I generate a List of (int, 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want `flatMap`?

```
rdd.flatMap { case ((x, y), z) => List((x, 1), (y, 1), (z, 1)) }
```

The above code produces `RDD[(Int, Int)]`, expanding each of the nested tuples in your RDD into three separate RDD elements.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't take three map functions but a single map function as shown below

```
inputRDD.map({case ((x,y),z) => ((x,1),(y,1),(z,1))})
```

Comment: Right, that's what I come up with at first, but what I need to generate is list((int, 1)), not list (((int,1), (int,1),(int,1)))